# Client-side pagination with jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

I know it's possible to do client-side sorting in jqGrid by setting loadonce = true but is it possible to do client-side paging as well?

I want to pass all the data (about 80 pages of JSON) to the client initially during page load and then, I don't want any server calls. I want jqGrid to handle both the paging and sorting.

Answer (score 1):

In lieu of reposting the question I'll suggest a link that might help someone, but it hasn't helped me yet:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=18/help/using-client-side-sorting-but-server-side-paging-using-jqgrid/page-1

I'd like assistance on getting client-side pagination with client-side sorting as well.